# Is it possible to loop through a list of functions stored in a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Basically, I am creating a game: Connect 4. I want the AI to check both horizontally and vertically if the user is about to win every time a move is made. The reality is, it should implement only one check at a time because you can't make 2 moves at once anyway.

So, I have created 2 check functions. One for horizontal checking and one for vertical checking. i.e:

Let's assume player counter is `'X'` and AI counter is `'O'`:

```
def horizonal_check():
    if 'XXX'= True: 
        AI='XXXO'
```

The if statement in my actual game is more complicated that this but in essence, this  is what it checks for then allows the AI to place its own counter in the appropriate place and stops me from winning.

```
def vertical_check():
    if 'XXX' = True: 
        AI = 'XXXO'
```

This implements the same strategy as the function above but the only difference is, it checks for the vertical combination of 3 counters in a row instead of the horizontal combination.

So what I really want to do is store this 2 check functions in a tuple then use a for loop to loop through each one. This ensures only one check runs at a time. Here is my for loop:

```
Checks = (horizontal_check(), vertical_check()) # Checks stored in a tuple

for c in Checks:
    return c
```

I want this for loop to loop through each individual check in the tuple one at a time. But it doesn't seem to work. The AI does nothing

Comment: You should not call the function in the tuple, but when you get it out: `c()`

Comment: it gives me an error when i do that: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently creating a tuple containing the return values for your two function calls, `None` and `None` respectively, not the functions themselves.

Add the functions:

```
Checks = (horizontal_check, vertical_check) # Checks stored in a tuple
```

and then call them:

```
for c in Checks:
    c()
```

Also, I am suspecting this is a trivialized example, but still:

- Your function names don't match.
- `'XXX' = True` isn't allowed (at least in an `if`), should be `'XXX' == True`.
- `return` in a `for` loop: it's a no-no.

Comment: When i do that, it gives me this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Do not use `Checks = (horizontal_check(), vertical_check())`; you're calling the functions if you do. Use `Checks = (horizontal_check, vertical_check) ` (*no parentheses -- i.e call*)

Comment: @PercyShey you are getting that error because inside `Checks` you are calling the functions instead of referring to them. Your function doesn't have a valid return call, so when you call them, they return a `None-Type` object. Your for loop is essentially looping through a tuple of two `None-Type` objects.

Comment: Note that you can either call the functions inside the tuple as you're doing, as long as these functions have a valid return call (the return values will be stored in the tuple, not the function call) or you can call them one at a time in the for loop as @JimFasarakis-Hilliard showed. But I think that in general the for loop is more efficient, because you have more control over when to call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell but i guess you want this

```
Checks = (horizontal_check, vertical_check) # do not call the function here...

return any(c() for c in Checks) #call it as you loop through ...
```

Comment: I think that it signals a wining move by the player ... so any winning move should short circuit and notify the AI that this game state leads to a loss ... at least that was my interpretation